# How to execute an update SQL query with a where statement referencing values in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to update records in a table using and SQL query which uses a where statement referencing another values located in another table.

In the example below, i have taken values according to a select query i built and relocated them to a table called "tblSearchEngine05".  At that point, i am trying to update a column in table "tblSearchEngin01" using a conditional query based on the values located in "tblSEarchEngine05". I am trying to use the two populated fields [tblSearchEngine05].[enddate] and [tblSearchEngine05].[startdate] as the values for the condition. Unfortunately there seems to be a syntax error message.

```
    Private Sub myComboBox_Change()


    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim period As String
    Dim dayOfWeek As Integer
    Dim monthOfQuarter As Integer

    period = Me.myComboBox
            startDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
    Select Case period
        Case "Today"
            endDate = DateAdd("d", 1, startDate)

            'deletes all records in holding table "tblsearchengine05"
            st_sql = "Delete [tblsearchengine05].[startdate]FROM tblsearchengine05"
             Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

            ' updates the holding table "tblSearchEngine05" to reflect the correct start and finish date
            Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
            Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSearchEngine05", dbOpenTable)
            rst.AddNew
            rst!startDate = startDate
            rst!FinishDate = endDate
            rst.Update
            rst.Close
            Set rst = Nothing


            ' clears the Query02DateSelect column on table tblSearchEngine01

        st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query02DateSelect = NULL"
        Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)


            ' updates the column [tblSearchEngine01].[query02dateselect] to identify which records contain the specified date range criteria

            st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01, tblSearchEngine05 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query02DateSelect = '1' WHERE (((tblSearchEngine01.[Automatic date of entry])>=([tblSearchEngine05].[StartDate]) And (tblSearchEngine01.[Automatic date of entry])<=([tblSearchEngine05].[FinishDate])))"
            Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

........

Comment: and that syntax error would be....?

Comment: There are two UPDATE statements against tbllSearchEngine01 - which one seems to throw the error?

Comment: The second one. The first one i use just to clear the column i would like to update. (it works fine)

Comment: I got it. Thank anyway

Comment: Code above is updated correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub myComboBox_Change()


    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim period As String
    Dim dayOfWeek As Integer
    Dim monthOfQuarter As Integer

    period = Me.myComboBox
            startDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
    Select Case period
        Case "Today"
            endDate = DateAdd("d", 1, startDate)

            'deletes all records in holding table "tblsearchengine05"
        st_sql = "Delete [tblsearchengine05].[startdate]FROM tblsearchengine05"
         Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

            ' updates the holding table "tblSearchEngine05" to reflect the correct start and finish date
            Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
            Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSearchEngine05", dbOpenTable)
            rst.AddNew
            rst!startDate = startDate
            rst!FinishDate = endDate
            rst.Update
            rst.Close
            Set rst = Nothing


            ' clears the Query02DateSelect column on table tblSearchEngine01

        st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query02DateSelect = NULL"
        Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)


            ' updates the column [tblSearchEngine01].[query02dateselect] to identify which records contain the specified date range criteria

       st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01, tblSearchEngine05 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query02DateSelect = '1' WHERE (((tblSearchEngine01.[Automatic date of entry])>=([tblSearchEngine05].[StartDate]) And (tblSearchEngine01.[Automatic date of entry])<=([tblSearchEngine05].[FinishDate])))"
        Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```